# Frame navigation in Windows runtime does not work

Tags: navigation, frame, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a windows runtime app that uses the frame control to navigate. I have a problem with the back button though. Consider this:

> MainPage (this is the launch page of the app)
>   ListPage (this page displays a list)
>   DetailsPage (shows details about the selected item from the list page.

When I click on back on the details page it skips back to the main page instead of going to the list page.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem concerns *double* navigation - your `frame.GoBack()` is called twice - once by `NavigationHelper` (which subscribes to `HardwareButtons.BackPressed`) and twice by EventHandler subscribed in App.xaml.cs.

Remove susbscription from App.xaml.cs and check if that helped:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
  //  HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed; // this line also fires frame.GoBack() (as default project template)
}
```

Comment: @sidy3d Are you able to share the code? In my example it solved the issue. Is there a chance that you haven't unsubscribed Eventhandler or call frame.GoBack() few times?

Comment: @sidy3d And [here you can download](http://1drv.ms/1g5QXU2) my simple example with the issue I've mentioned. Maybe it will help.